# Keep getting access violations when running my DSW algorithm

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I feel like I've been staring myself blind att this code for the last couple of hours. I'm studying c++ programming and one of my current assignments is to add a DSW algorithm to balance my binary search tree (the previous assignment). I've got a test program that I run the code through (that was provided by my teachers) and I keep getting access violations when I run the tests, and I am not completely sure as to why. Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
    template <class T>
    void BinaryTree<T>::DSW_balance() {
        if (_root != nullptr) {
            create_backbone();
            create_perfect_tree(_number_of_nodes);
        }
    }

    template <class T>
    void BinaryTree<T>::create_backbone() {
        BinaryTreeNode<T> *grandparent = _root;
        BinaryTreeNode<T> *parent = _root;
        BinaryTreeNode<T> *left_child = _root;

        while (parent != nullptr) {
            if (left_child != nullptr) {
                left_child = parent->get_left();

                if (parent == _root) {
                    rotate_right(nullptr, parent, parent->_left);
                } else {
                    rotate_right(grandparent, parent, parent->_left);
                }
                parent = left_child;
            } else {
                grandparent = parent;
                parent = parent->get_right();
            }
        }
    }

    template <class T>
    void BinaryTree<T>::rotate_right(BinaryTreeNode<T> *grandparent, BinaryTreeNode<T> *parent, BinaryTreeNode<T> *left_child) {
        if (parent != _root) {
            grandparent->_right = left_child;
        } else {
            _root = left_child;
        }
        parent->_left = left_child->get_right();
        left_child->_right = parent;
    }

    template <class T>
    void BinaryTree<T>::rotate_left(BinaryTreeNode<T> *grandparent, BinaryTreeNode<T> *parent, BinaryTreeNode<T> *right_child) {
        if (parent != _root) {
            grandparent->_left = right_child;
        } else {
            _root = right_child;
        }
        parent->_right = right_child->get_left();
        right_child->_left = parent;
    }

    template <class T>
    void BinaryTree<T>::create_perfect_tree(int n) {
        int m = pow(2, floor(log2(n + 1))) - 1;
        compact(n - m);

        while (m > 1) {
            m /= 2;
            compact(m);
        }
    }

    template <class T>
    void BinaryTree<T>::compact(int n) {
        static BinaryTreeNode<T> *grandparent = _root;
        static BinaryTreeNode<T> *parent = _root;
        static BinaryTreeNode<T> *right_child = _root;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            right_child = parent->get_right();

            if (parent == _root) {
                rotate_left(nullptr, parent, parent->_right);
            } else {
                rotate_left(grandparent, parent, parent->_right);
            }
            parent = right_child;
            grandparent = right_child;
            parent = parent->get_right();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Start by catching the crash in a debugger, to locate when and where in your code it happens. If it doesn't help by examining variables and their values at the point of the crash, then try to construct the smallest possible tree that leads to the crash, and step through your code statement by statement until you notice something wrong happening.

Comment: And if you have a version control system, then roll back until the code works, and then step forward until it happens. The last change applied must contain if not the error itself, the trigger that cause it to happen. That makes it easier to find the code responsible (as it's less to go through).

Comment: I see far too few checks for null pointers. Add checks, even where you believe that it can't possibly happen.